# Saving hundreds of thousands of records at a time in SQL Server using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, memory-management

I have a query that fetches **200,000 records at a time with 74 columns** from the server and then I have to **insert them into my table on a client machine**. What is the best way to do this without getting an "out of memory" error in ASP.Net (using C# and SQL Server 2005 database).

Comment: Lakhs = 100000 (Indian unit)?  Not everyone here is fluent in global measuring units, you know...

Comment: 200000 records x 74 columns (say 512 bytes, not sure how many strings you have) = 100MB of storage just for the data, not counting object overheads.  Your server should handle 100MB quite well, unless you are trying to run multiple instances at the same time.  Why are you getting out of memory errors?

Comment: And for this database-load task, why are you using ASP.NET in the first place?  It seems like the wrong technology to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DataReader and pass that as input to SqlBulkCopy using an appropriate batchsize.

Answer (score -1):

### In Class.cs

```
 public int Saving(int s)
 {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(classname.ConnectionString)){
    cn.Open();
    SqlTransaction trans;
    trans = cn.BeginTransaction();
    try{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Storedprocedurename", cn, trans);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@spparameter", SqlDbType.Int).Value = s;
    int DataResult =Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    if (DataResult != 0)
    {
    trans.Commit();
    return DataResult;
    }
    else
    {
    trans.Rollback();
    return -1;
    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    string msg = ex.Message;
    trans.Rollback();
    trans.Dispose();
    return 0;
   }
}
```